# How to draw leader lines

Tags: r, charts, line

The task is to draw a 3D pie chart with leading lines (leader lines in Microsoft Excel) starting from the midpoint of each sector to the associated label.

Using the below code, I am able to draw a 3D pie chart with sectors and labels and with different colors for each sector. I also wanted to include the leading lines (called leader lines in Microsoft Excel). I do not know how we draw leading lines for 3D pie charts in R. Please help me with an R script that can draw leading lines for 3D pie charts.

The initial code is as below:

```
  library(plotrix)
 
 # Data for Pie chart
 x = c(20, 20, 20,20,20)
 labels = c('breakfast', 'brunch', 'lunch', 'snacks', 'dinner')
 colors = c('#4286f4','#bb3af2','#ed2f52','#efc023','#ea7441')
 
 # Give the chart file a name.
 png(file = "diet3d.png")

 pie3D(x, labels=labels, explode=0.1, height=0.05, main='Daily Diet Plan', col=colors, radius = 0.5) 
 dev.off()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Thank you.